# Unable to remote deploy package due to inaccessible ADMIN$ share on target domain Workstation

Tags: network-share, windows-10, share

I've got this laptop here running Windows 10. I'm trying to deploy a PDQ package to it but I'm getting a "Computer unreachable or offline" error. According to PQD it's because it can't access the ADMIN$ share.

I can ping the workstation via IP and FQDN.

I have verified that the computer browser and netlogon services are running. I've tried turning off windows firewall completely. The remote account has domain admin privileges and the workstation is a domain machine.

I've removed it and re-added it to the domain.

When I try and access it remotely via Windows explorer (\\computername\sharename) and then run the troubleshooter it states that "The remote device or resource won't accept the connection"

Is there some Windows feature that isn't installed for some reason?

Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks in advance.

Update: I ran the network troubleshooter from a different workstation and this is what the report has said.

> The remote device or resource won't accept the connection
>
> The device or resource (ComputerName) is not set up to accept connections on port "The File and printer sharing (SMB)".

I did this while the firewall was off

Update2: I've tried disabling and enabling SMB2 via Powershell using this page as instruction https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows

Then restarted. Still no luck.

I'm just going to reset the damn thing, which is what I should have done at the start but oh well, there goes 6 hours lol.

Comment: Is the Server service running? Is File and Printer Sharing bound to the NIC?

Comment: I just went to check the NIC bindings but the "adapters and bindings" tab is not there. I've just got the "Provider Order" tab. Also yes the server service is running

Comment: just found out they removed the Adapters and bindings tab in Win 10.

Comment: @joeqwerty Also, I just tried to RDP into the workstation using an admin account and it said "Logon failure: the user has not been granted the reuested logon type at this computer" RDP is definitely turned on and the user account has full admin rights to the device.

Comment: File and Printer Sharing isn't in the Bindings settings. It's on the Networking tab of the NIC properties. It's a checkbox. Checking and unchecking the box binds and unbinds it to the NIC.

Comment: The user having "full admin rights" to the computer doesn't mean that the user is a member of the Remote Desktop Users group, which they need to be in order to log on via RDP. Make sure you check that their user account is a member of that group.

Comment: Ok, I added the user to the RDP group and verified that File and Printer Sharing was turned on on the NIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the PC to factory default sure worked. But if you've had this issue before and know a better solution please post.

Edit: I'll update this as well since I've run into this a couple more times since then. Removing the PC from the domain and re-adding also works.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is/was posted a few months ago. I was having the same issue. I discovered that those machines that were not visible had network discovery disabled. I created a Powershell script package through PDQ and fired it off to those machines and viola! They are invisible no more. They can run but they cant hide.